# Array method and join function combined output in javascript unable to understand

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I defined `myArr` variable in `javascript` as follows:

```
var myArr= Array(3);
```

When I `consoled` the value of `myArr` it gave the following output:

```
[undefined × 3]
```

When I used the javascript [join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) function which is as follows:

```
myArr.join('X');
```

And `consoled` the output I got the following:

```
"XX"
```

Can somebody explain me why I got this output? I was expecting the output to be

```
"undefinedXundefinedX"
```

Comment: `undefined` is not really a value.. Just a representation of length of `array`.. Could be read as `[NOTHING, NOTHING, NOTHING]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.prototype.join will perform the string conversions of all array elements and joined into one string. If an element is undefined or null, it is converted to the empty string. [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

All the undefined elements are equal to ["", "", ""].join('X')

Answer (score 1):

`Array(3)` creates an array of three **empty holes**.

To achieve your desired result, you need to fill the holes: `Array(3).fill()`

Answer (score 0):

`Array(3)` will create an array of length 3.

On consoling `myArr` it will log empty array

[**join**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) will join all elements of the array into a string